# My UWP VPN app add to username another symbols

Tags: c#, networking, uwp, windows-runtime, vpn

I create vpn profile from my UWP app

```
public async void connect()
        {
            var config = @"
            <VPNProfile>  
                <ProfileName>testConnection</ProfileName>
                    <NativeProfile>
                        <Servers>***.**.**.***</Servers>
                        <RoutingPolicyType>SplitTunnel</RoutingPolicyType>
                        <NativeProtocolType>IKEv2</NativeProtocolType>
                        <Authentication>
                            <UserMethod>Eap</UserMethod>
                            <Eap>
                                <Configuration>
                                    <EapHostConfig xmlns=""http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig"">
                                        <EapMethod>
                                            <Type xmlns = ""microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon"">26</Type>
                                            <VendorId xmlns = ""microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon"">0</VendorId>
                                            <VendorType xmlns = ""microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon"">0</VendorType>
                                            <AuthorId xmlns = "microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon"">0</AuthorId>
                                        </EapMethod>
                                        <Config xmlns = ""microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig"">
                                            <Eap xmlns = "".microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1"">
                                                <Type>26</Type>
                                                <EapType xmlns = ""microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2ConnectionPropertiesV1"">
                                                    <UseWinLogonCredentials>false</UseWinLogonCredentials>
                                                </EapType>
                                            </Eap>
                                        </Config>
                                    </EapHostConfig>
                                </Configuration>
                            </Eap>
                        </Authentication>
                    </NativeProfile>
                    <RequireVpnClientAppUI>true</RequireVpnClientAppUI>
                    <RememberCredentials>true</RememberCredentials>
            </VPNProfile>";

            VpnManagementErrorStatus profileStatus = await windowsVpnManager.AddProfileFromXmlAsync(config);

            var profiles = await windowsVpnManager.GetProfilesAsync();

            var profile = profiles.First(p => p.ProfileName == "testProfile") as VpnNativeProfile;

            var connectionStatus = await windowsVpnManager.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(profile, new PasswordCredential { UserName = "test", Password = "test123" });

            Debug.Print($"Connection status -> {connectionStatus}");
        }
```

If I try to connect to a server, I see at server logs **received EAP identity '?\test'**.

My username credential transform from "test" to "?\test"

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Does this behavior only happen in UWP? Does it have the same behavior(get “?\test”) in other apps using this VPNProfile?

Comment: If i connect from windows setting by this VPN profile , it's works normal.

Comment: What is the return value of `windowsVpnManager.AddProfileFromXmlAsync(config)` in debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already answered by Peter Smith on Microsoft Q&A here: [UWP VPN app add to username another symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160967/my-uwp-vpn-app-add-to-username-another-symbols)

I will post a summary here so others who meet the same question could know the reason.

Answer from Perter:

The code adds the "?" because that's what the Microsoft RRAS server is expecting to see. The Windows IKEv2 was designed to work as part of the entire Domain solution. Each user is part of some "Domain" -- in some companies, everyone is in one domain; in others people get put into different domains.

The VPN developers think that because you're providing a user name ("test") without a domain name, a dummy domain name ("?") is added along with the needed backslash.